# Show by using vectors that the two diagonals of a square are equal in dimension

Tags: analytic-geometry

and also perpendicular to each other?

> how can we prove that ...please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `|A|` be Euclidean length of vector `A`

Now as per Pythagoras theorem: For two orthogonal vector - say `A` & `B` - in 2D,
`|A+B| = sqrt(|A|^2 + |B|^2)`

Now, let `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are the corner point of given square in clockwise direction and `ab`, `bc`, `cd`, and `da` are vectors which represents the sides of square.
So, `|ab| = |bc| = |cd| = |da|`

So, dimension of diagonal:
{Dimension_of `ac` or `ca`} = `|ac|` = `sqrt(|ab|^2 + |bc|^2)` = `sqrt(|ab|^2 + |ad|^2)` = `|bd|` = {Dimension_of `bd` or `db`}

Above argument is correct for 2D. and Square is a planar figure, so we can apply these rules.

So, this proves that, two diagonals of a square are equal in dimension.
*Done!*

Answer (score 2):

A hint. We have a general arrangement like this

[image: square!]

If we let $\vec{BA} = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ then what will the vector $\vec{DA}$ be? How do we represent a vector perpendicular to a given vector?

What about $\vec{CA}$? And $\vec{BD}$? Can they be written in terms of $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{DA}$?

How do we determine when two vectors are perpendicular?

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors are orthogonal if and only if their dot product is 0. Can you use that fact in your proof?